# Limit Is Unique-Proof Understanding

Tags: calculus

I am trying to understand the proof of limit being unique.

I have manage to understand most of [this proof](https://mathchaos.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/prove-that-the-limit-of-a-function-is-unique/)

[image]

but failed to understand why it must be equal to $0$ and why $|p-q|\leq0$ and not $|p-q|<0$  as the definition of $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

Comment: The reason is that $|p-q| < 0$ doesn't make sense. You can't have a positive number be less than $0$ (with the usual ordering on the real numbers). What you really have is that $0\le |p-q|$ is less than *every* positive number, so it must be $0$.

Comment: The last line of the proof you cite is slightly sloppy and I would write it slightly differently. For example, if everywhere we write inequalities which are strict ($<$ instead of $\leq$), then I hope we can agree that

$$|p - q | < \epsilon \ \text{ for all } \epsilon > 0 \ \Longrightarrow \ p = q$$

Comment: Intuitively, how many numbers  do you know  that are between 0 and *every* positive number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is a bit sloppy. In the line
$$|p-q| \leq |p-f(x)| + |f(x)-q| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon,$$
the second inequality should in fact be strict; that is, we should have
$$|p-q|<\epsilon$$
for all $\epsilon > 0$. If $|p-q|$ is less than all positive numbers, it cannot be itself positive. On the other hand, $|x| \geq 0$ for all $x$. Therefore, $|p-q| = 0$, so $p=q$.

Answer (score 2):

First of $|p-q|<0$ cannot hold since $|x|\ge 0$ for any $x\in\Bbb R$.  Now, because $|p-q|<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, we cannot have $|p-q|>0$.  If $|p-q|>0$, let $\epsilon=|p-q|$.  This contradicts that $|p-q|<\epsilon$.